# Errors appear when im trying to create Nuxt.JS project

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, yarnpkg

I am trying to create a Nuxt project using Yarn, with additional plugins: Express, Vuetify, PWA. When creating, a number of console errors arise, because of which it is impossible to assemble the initial assembly. Here is a screenshot of the errors that occur, help to fix that problems
[Console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGBz5.png)

Comment: Could you please post the error as text and not as a screenshot?

Comment: @DelenaMalan i cant copy it from console

Comment: what is your node version? did you try install nuxt with `npm`? can you give us a error log? (in your image the console say where is it)